# Has the here maps places api been withdrawn as the code has stopped working?

Tags: javascript, maps, here-api

Has the here places api been withdrawn as the code has stopped working? Code that has been working on my map for several years, but does not seem to work any more and I cannot find any information that the api has been withdrawn.  The code allowed me to look for dining, accommodation etc. within a radius.
[https://places.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/explore/places?callback=nokia.places.comm.data.clb[%27105%27]&Accept-Language=en-GB&app_id=myhereid&app_code=CfHNOXM2g0pMfgxwnVQtCg&xnlp=CL_JSMv2.5.3,SID_638D0396-961E-4B98-969C-749E6746522B&cat=going-out&at=48.3705449,10.89779](https://places.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/explore/places?callback=nokia.places.comm.data.clb%5B%27105%27%5D&Accept-Language=en-GB&app_id=myhereid&app_code=CfHNOXM2g0pMfgxwnVQtCg&xnlp=CL_JSMv2.5.3,SID_638D0396-961E-4B98-969C-749E6746522B&cat=going-out&at=48.3705449,10.89779)

The error is: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Do I need a different access address or have here maps simple withdrawn the service?
Thanks for any assistance as I have tried a number of different combinations to get it working.

Comment: related?: https://www.here.com/docs/bundle/places-search-api-migration-guide/page/topics-api/search.html